# Is Null for Int in c# same as 0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I understand that Int is a non nullable value but there are cases in MVC where we use

```
public ActionResult Myfunction(int modelattr)
{
    if (modelattr != 0) // how is null handled as 0?
    {
        // do some code
    }
}
```

How is the Null handled as 0?

Comment: Null cannot be represented by int type. 0 is the default value of int type. There is int? or Nullable<int> that can handle null

Comment: null != 0, 0 != null. null == null. 0 == 0

Comment: What are you asking here? `modelattr` is an int. Why do you think it's null?

Comment: Thinking of 0 as `null` is a very C thing to do. In C#, `null` is its own thing, and is not the same as 0.

Comment: @JimMischel In MVC when you navigate to a actionresult `/controller/action/int`. However when you google examples you will find that there is no null handling(unasigned) procedure if the user inputs `/controller/action`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers above have given you ample information on the reasons that an int cannot be null and how you can create a nullable int.  However, to address the issue you are looking into (not having an ID passed to an action), you would need to have the following:

In your route configuration (note the optional ID parameter):

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then adjust your controller action signature to match the following along with a null value test:

```
public ActionResult Myfunction(int? modelattr)
{
    if (modelattr.HasValue()) //this will test if the nullable int has a value or is null
    {
        // do some code
    }
}
```

Lastly, you may want to invert your if statement to reduce nesting of code execution blocks depending on what you want to do if the parameter is null.  For instance:

```
public ActionResult Myfunction(int? modelattr)
{
    if (!modelattr.HasValue()) //this will test if the nullable int has a value or is null
    {
        //throw an exception or return a route to another page
    }
    //now do your processing, no need to have to stay inside of the if statement.
}
```

Answer (score 9):

An `int` cannot be `null`.  Period.  Many systems use `0` as a "default" value and apply special logic in that case but it cannot be null.

An `int?` (shortcut for `Nullable<int>`) CAN bu `null` but your example does not use that.

Comment: It is probably worth adding that `int?` CAN be null. The `int?` syntax is a shortcut for `Nullable<int>`. So it is not the case that you can't have a 'nullable int'. Just that `int` itself can't ever be `null`.

Comment: and in your sample modelattr is an int. So you never cann pass an int? to your your function.

Comment: Now comes a rush of duplicate answers -.-

Answer (score 3):

Structs can not be null and [`int` is a struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) (`int` is a alias for `System.Int32` BTW).

If you want to know what the "default" value would be if you did not assign anything to the value (like for example you had a `int` as a property of a class that you never set) you can get the value of `default(int)`.

If you do need a struct to be a null value you can use the [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) wrapper. Often this can be shortened to `int?`.

Answer (score 3):

So what you're really asking is, given this route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

How, then, is the controller passed an `id` value of 0 if none is specified.

There are (at least) two possibilities:

1. There is some code that checks for a missing id value and supplies 0. Your controller's default method could do that, for example.
2. There is another route that supplies the default.

Whatever the case, there is nothing that's converting a null to 0. There is code somewhere that is supplying a default when the id is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

int never holds null because it is non-nullable value type. If you want then try assigning a null value to int as follows

```
        int i = null;
```

It will give you error as
    **Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type**